# Android Video Merging Side by Side

Tags: java, android, merge, video-processing

i want to merge/stitch two videos side by side i am using FFMPEG for merging it take too much processing time is there any other way or library that merge video side by side Frame..Just like tiktok duet.if any other way please guide or provide reference links thanks..